# memcached restart starts a new memcached and doesn't kill the old one

Tags: memcached

I'm running my rails app in production mode and in staging mode on the same server, in different folders.  They both use memcache-client which requires memcached to be running.

As yet i haven't set up a deploy script and so just do a deploy manually by sshing onto the server, going to the appropriate directory, updating the code, restarting memcached and then restarting unicorn (the processes which actually run the rails app).  I restart memcached thus:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart &
```

This starts a new memcached, but it doesn't kill the old one:  check it out:

```
ip-<an-ip>:test.millionaire[subjects]$ ps afx | grep memcache
11176 pts/2    S+     0:00  |           \_ grep --color=auto memcache
10939 pts/3    R      8:13              \_ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
 7453 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1

ip-<an-ip>:test.millionaire[subjects]$ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart &
[1] 11187

ip-<an-ip>:test.millionaire[subjects]$ ps afx | grep memcache
11187 pts/2    T      0:00  |           \_ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
11199 pts/2    S+     0:00  |           \_ grep --color=auto memcache
10939 pts/3    R      8:36              \_ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
 7453 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
ip-<an-ip>:test.millionaire[subjects]$ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart &
[2] 11208
ip-<an-ip>:test.millionaire[subjects]$ ps afx | grep memcache
11187 pts/2    T      0:00  |           \_ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
11208 pts/2    R      0:01  |           \_ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
11218 pts/2    S+     0:00  |           \_ grep --color=auto memcache
10939 pts/3    R      8:42              \_ sudo /etc/init.d/memcached restart
 7453 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1
```

What might be causing it is there's another memcached running - see the bottom line.  I'm mystified as to where this is from and my instinct is to kill it but i thought i'dd better check with someone who actually knows more about memcached than i do.

Grateful for any advice - max

EDIT - solution

I figured this out after a bit of detective work with a colleague.  In the rails console i typed CACHE.stats which prints out a hash of values, including "pid", which i could see was set to the instance of memcached which wasn;t started with memcached restart, ie this process:

```
7453 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u nobody -l 127.0.0.1
```

The memcached control script (ie that defines the start, stop and restart commands), is in `/etc/init.d/memcached`

A line in this says

```
# Edit /etc/default/memcached to change this.
ENABLE_MEMCACHED=no
```

So i looked in `/etc/default/memcached`, which was also set to  `ENABLE_MEMCACHED=no`

So, this was basically preventing memcached from being stopped and started.   I changed it to  `ENABLE_MEMCACHED=yes`, then it would stop and start fine.  Now when i stop and start memcached, it's the above process, the in-use memcached, that's stopped and started.

Answer (score 8):

try using:

```
 killall memcached
```

Comment: Thanks greg, i know how to kill processes but like i said i wanted to find out what was actually happening rather than just work around it.  I figured it out anyway, see EDIT